# Block 'kw=' Query String

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I keep getting nonsense hits to my site like:

- myurl.com/?kw=antivirus*protection
- myurl.com/?kw=a+casino
- myurl.com/?kw=.confused.com
- myurl.com/?kw=whatevernonsense

Also, if it matters, it is a self-hosted Wordpress site. I've tried many permutations to the following, but it isn't working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} kw
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit: I've tested the above code in a separate directory, and it works fine. Below is the Wordpress chunk I've narrowed it down to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} kw
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

# Use PHP5.3 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This rule should work, just place it as very first rule.

Comment: I added it as the very first rule. No luck :/

Comment: You have some other issue (some plugin may be). Test this rule outside WP and it will definitely work.

Comment: Make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the following to the WP chunk of the .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # These 2 lines block any request coming in with `/?kw=`
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?kw=
    RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```