# How do you deny query from htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

How do I deny access to a specific query across the whole website?

For example, whenever someone goes on www.example.com/?hello=123 they get redirected to www.example.com

Comment: This would be solved with a redirect rule.

Comment: The rewriting module offers conditions that can work on the query string. Take a look into the documentation, it comes with really good examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: If you just looked around or did a search, there are plenty of examples you can use and tailor to your needs. like [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/342774/use-apache-to-block-a-url-with-specific-query-string) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969856/block-kw-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hello=123$
RewriteRule ^ www.example.com [L,R]
```